# What does Trusted = yes/no mean in Sql connection string?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ado.net

What does Trusted = yes/no mean in Sql connection string?

I am creating a connection string as below :

```
            string con= string.Format(
                "user id=admin;password=admin;server={0};Trusted_Connection=yes;database=dbtest;connection timeout=600",
                _sqlServer);
```

Please Help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Integrated Security` or `Trusted_Connection`

When `false`, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When `true`, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.

Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [connectionstring,com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) for detailed description of all the various SQL Server connecion string properties.  Specifically, [this article](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords):

Answer (score 1):

SSPI stands for Security Support Provider Interface.

The SSPI allows an application to use any of the available security packages on a system without changing the interface to use security services. The SSPI does not establish logon credentials because that is generally a privileged operation handled by the operating system.

Usually a .NETconnection string looks like this, of course you will have your own server, database names.

`"Data Source=localhost\sql2012;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;
Integrated Security=SSPI"`

Other than `SSPI` you can also use `"true"`.

Integrated Security actually ensures that you are connecting with SQL Server using Windows Authentication, not SQL Authentication; which requires username and password to be provided with the connecting string.

Comment: Ummm; the OP isn't asking about `Integrated Security` or its `SSPI` value.

Comment: Agreed. But the accepted answer calls out SSPI as the "Highly Recommended" value, so I suspect this was posted to clarify the purpose and function of SSPI.