# Database uses windows authentication instead of server

Tags: sql-server, qt, qsqldatabase

I have a local MSSQL database with several users. I use server authentication in Management Studio successfully, but when I try to connect the database in QT it uses local windows username instead of the one I provided.

Code:

```
db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER={8SQLQT};DATABASE=GradingSystem;Trusted_Connection=yes;");
db.setUserName("ivanov");
db.setPassword("1");
db.open(); 
qDebug() << db.userName() << db.lastError();
```

Debug output:

> "ivanov" QSqlError("18456", "QODBC3: Unable to connect", "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user '8sqlqt\asdfgh'.")

**asdfgh** is a name of local windows user.

Comment: What happens if you add `Integrated  Security=False` into your databaseName string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does Trusted = yes/no mean in Sql connection string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242993/what-does-trusted-yes-no-mean-in-sql-connection-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER={8SQLQT};DATABASE=GradingSystem;Trusted_Connection=no;user_id=ivanov;password=1;");
db.open();
qDebug() << db.userName() << db.lastError();
```