# C# Program is using my Windows AD authentication to connect to my database instead of the connection string I coded into it. Why?

Tags: c#, database

The title almost says it all, but I'll provide a little background.

I am working on adding password hashing to a program written by a team member who rather suddenly departed this world. I have all of the original source, and have made appropriate changes.

The issue arises when, after looking at the active connections on the database, the connection it is making is under my Windows Activate Directory username, rather than the connection string I give to SqlConnection().

I am not traditionally a C# programmer, but the language is very easy to pick up on. For those more accustomed to C#'s particular ins and outs, what can I do to assure that I'm connecting through the connection string passed to SqlConnection()?

This is important since people who are not me and have no authorization to the database are not going to be able to even validate their DB stored usernames + password without using that connection string.

EDIT: My current connection string is as follows:

> user id=[uid];password=[password];server=[server];Trusted_Connection=yes;database=[dbName];connection timeout=30"

Comment: Can you show your (redacted) connection string?

Comment: I have edited it in.

Comment: When trusted connection is specified the user/password is always the one who started the process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Trusted_Connection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242993/what-does-trusted-yes-no-mean-in-sql-connection-string) is an alias for `Integrated Security`, which means "use my Windows account". Remove it from your connection string.