# Win Forms / SQL Server Authentication Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm working on a C# application that's built on Winforms. The application connects to a SQL database, retrieves data and then inserts the data into a MySQL database. The application works perfectly in two separate environments however when I deploy it and try to run, I get an authentication error. The error relates to the username and password not matching. The strange thing is that the username that is returned is not the username in the connection string but rather the user's Active Directory login details and not the username that is stored in the application.

I'm confused as to how this would happen and would appreciate assistance in troubleshooting. Is there a way to force SQL-authentication over Windows-authentication? Is that even the problem?

My connection string is based off inputs on the form, those inputs are validated to ensure they're not blank and then passed to this method to test connectivity:

```
// test the inputs as a connection string - can we connect to the SQL DB?
public bool validateSQLconnection(string host, string user, string db, string pass)
{
    bool connection = false;
    string connstring = "Database=" + db + ";Server=" + host + ";Password=" + pass + ";User id=" + user + ";Trusted_Connection = yes;connection timeout=5";

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connstring);
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        connection = true;
        var response = MessageBox.Show("Connected to SQL DB:" + db + " Successfully");
        if (response.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            myConnection.Close();
            SFConnectionString = connstring;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

    return connection;
}
```

Comment: Likely the connection string is changed in that env. App.config vs. machine.config, you need to track it down. Print/log the connection string used before the connect attempt, to make sure is the one you think it is.

Comment: You really should show the connection string in your question (omit actual username and password) and debug to confirm the correct connection string gets utilized in your application.

Comment: if you use username and password in connection string, then is not Windows auth, is SQL Authentication. If you want to use Windows Authentication you must to configure in your connection string to accept Windows Authenticantion. And if you have a Active Directory Group of users, add this group to Security of your SQL and DB.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I've updated the question, sorry about that.

Comment: @M56, I'm not specifying Windows auth, I'm avoiding that entirely but it appears that it's using it based on the username that the exception shows

Comment: @Daniel I though `Trusted_Connection = yes` does mean use Windows Auth, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242993/what-does-trusted-yes-no-mean-in-sql-connection-string

Comment: Rather than make up your own connection string via string concatenation, you might want to look into the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) which is specifically made to generate valid connection strings.

Comment: `Trusted_Connection` accepted values are `true` and `false`. Not sure how it works with `yes`, apparently on some environments is taken as 'true' on some is not.

Comment: Thank you @mason I will look into this in future and implement on the current application but for the sake of expediting the application deployment, M56's answer resolved the issue immediately!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string connstring = "Database=" + db + ";Server=" + host + ";Password=" + pass + ";User id=" + user + ";Integrated Security=false;connection timeout=5";
```

With "Integrated Security= false" you define the user to connect in connection string, see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(VS.71).aspx)

Hope this help!