# VS2022 ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API project running local - "Unable to connect to web server - Project name"

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022, iis-express

When I run the ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API on a new laptop with VS2022 - either in IIS Express or Project mode - I get this error:

> Unable to connect to web server

VS 2022 installed a local certificate when running the first time. But the Swagger page should appear in the browser.

> 2023-09-27T22:11:02.6041254Z Failed to send email:
> MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException: An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.
>
> This usually means that the SSL certificate presented by the server is not trusted by the system for one or more of the following reasons:
>
> 1. The server is using a self-signed certificate which cannot be verified.
> 2. The local system is missing a Root or Intermediate certificate needed to verify the server's certificate.
> 3. A Certificate Authority CRL server for one or more of the certificates in the chain is temporarily unavailable.
> 4. The certificate presented by the server is expired or invalid.
>
> Another possibility is that you are trying to connect to a port which does not support SSL/TLS.
>
> It is also possible that the set of SSL/TLS protocols supported by the client and server do not match.
>
> See https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#SslHandshakeException for possible solutions.

Comment: Regarding "Unable to connect to web server" you need to show more details (screen shots, or video clips). The MailKit exception, however, is caused by the certificate used on the IMAP/SMTP server you configured, not the server certificate used by IIS Express or Kestrel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I cannot share the code or screenshot since it is restricted. The Asp.net core web API run on other's laptop. The new laptop face this problem but other API project works which is similar and use DotNet 6.0. May I know what is the root cause. May I know where can I see the local certificate generated by VS2022

Comment: `where can I see the local certificate generated by VS2022` --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNQjn.png

Comment: found the solution. the issue is db connection string missing this properties "Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;" but is it safe to add this property in production?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1243006) may help you.